# Combining low frequency counts

Tags: r, categorical-data

Trying to collapse a nominal categorical vector by combining low frequency counts into an 'Other' category:

The data (column of a dataframe) looks like this, and contains information for all 50 states:

```
California
Florida
Alabama
...
```

`table(colname)/length(colname)`correctly returns the frequencies, and what I'm trying to do is to lump anything below a given threshold (say f=0.02) together. What is the correct approach?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: There is now, trying to figure out how to combine this information to collapse the categories of the original vector.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163778/how-do-you-find-a-cutting-point-strong-slope-within-one-dimensional-data/163787#163787

Comment: Tim - Thanks, it's not exactly what I'm trying to do (although it is a useful technique in those circumstances).

Comment: and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/how-do-i-group-a-list-of-numeric-values-into-ranges/4345#4345

Answer (score 11):

From the sounds of it, something like the following should work for you:

```
condenseMe <- function(vector, threshold = 0.02, newName = "Other") {
  toCondense <- names(which(prop.table(table(vector)) < threshold))
  vector[vector %in% toCondense] <- newName
  vector
}
```

Try it out:

```
## Sample data
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", sample(letters[1:10], 55, TRUE)))

round(prop.table(table(a)), 2)
# a
#    a    A    b    B    c    C    d    D    e    E    f    g    h 
# 0.07 0.02 0.07 0.02 0.10 0.02 0.10 0.02 0.12 0.02 0.07 0.12 0.13 
#    i    j 
# 0.08 0.07 

a
#  [1] "c" "d" "d" "e" "j" "h" "c" "h" "g" "i" "g" "d" "f" "D" "g" "h"
# [17] "h" "a" "b" "h" "e" "g" "h" "b" "d" "e" "e" "g" "i" "f" "d" "e"
# [33] "g" "c" "g" "a" "B" "i" "i" "b" "i" "j" "f" "d" "c" "h" "E" "j"
# [49] "j" "c" "C" "e" "f" "a" "a" "h" "e" "c" "A" "b"

condenseMe(a)
#  [1] "c"     "d"     "d"     "e"     "j"     "h"     "c"     "h"    
#  [9] "g"     "i"     "g"     "d"     "f"     "Other" "g"     "h"    
# [17] "h"     "a"     "b"     "h"     "e"     "g"     "h"     "b"    
# [25] "d"     "e"     "e"     "g"     "i"     "f"     "d"     "e"    
# [33] "g"     "c"     "g"     "a"     "Other" "i"     "i"     "b"    
# [41] "i"     "j"     "f"     "d"     "c"     "h"     "Other" "j"    
# [49] "j"     "c"     "Other" "e"     "f"     "a"     "a"     "h"    
# [57] "e"     "c"     "Other" "b"
```

Note, however, that if you are dealing with `factor`s, you should convert them with `as.character` first.

Answer (score 5):

Hadley Wickham's `forcats` package (available on CRAN since 2016-08-29) has a handy function `fct_lump()` which lumps together levels of a factor according to different criteria.

OP's requirement to lump together factors below a threshold of 0.02 can be achieved by

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", sample(letters[1:10], 55, TRUE)))
forcats::fct_lump(a, prop = 0.02)
```

> ```
>  [1] c     d     d     e     j     h     c     h     g     i     g     d    
> [13] f     Other g     h     h     a     b     h     e     g     h     b    
> [25] d     e     e     g     i     f     d     e     g     c     g     a    
> [37] Other i     i     b     i     j     f     d     c     h     Other j    
> [49] j     c     Other e     f     a     a     h     e     c     Other b    
> Levels: a b c d e f g h i j Other
> ```

Note that the sample data from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385807/3817004) has been used for comparison.

---

The function offers even more possibilities, e.g., it can keep the 5 factor levels with the lowest frequencies and lumps together the other levels:

```
forcats::fct_lump(a, n = -5)
```

> ```
>  [1] Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other
> [13] Other D     Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other
> [25] Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other
> [37] B     Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other Other E     Other
> [49] Other Other C     Other Other Other Other Other Other Other A     Other
> Levels: A B C D E Other
> ```

Comment: If trying to override values/make a new column make sure to wrap `fct_lump` in `mutate()`

Comment: @OliverOliver Please, can you elaborate why you believe that `mutate()` is *required*, here? `mutate()` works on a `tibble` or `data.frame` while  `fct_lump()` works with any vector of factors and may be called, e.g., from base R or within a `data.table` expression. Thank you.

Comment: It's not required. Common usage of tidyverse verbs is in a chain with pipes, usually acting on a dataframe/tibble, so I thought I would make that caveat since I'm slow and it took me a minute to realize that in order to change a dataframe, I would need to use mutate. Feel free to disreguard.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the game, but you may use my package [DataExplorer](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DataExplorer). The `group_category` function is exactly what you are looking for. There are other options too, you can type `?group_category` to find out more.

For example, in your case:

```
library(DataExplorer)
group_category(data, "colname", 0.02, update = TRUE)
```

[Here](https://boxuancui.github.io/DataExplorer/reference/group_category.html) are more examples.

Answer (score 2):

I used an upadated version of the condense me function:

```
condenseMe <- function(vector, name, limit) {

  toCondense <- names(which(prop.table(table(vector)) < limit))
  levels(vector)[levels(vector) %in% toCondense] <- name

  vector
}
```

Note: If among the levels there is NA set as level, in some cases condenseMe function will replace NA level with NA as missing values. That´s what happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work, but it's quite ugly.  Is there a more elegant solution?

```
collapsecatetgory <- function(x, p) {
levels_len = length(levels(x))
levels(x)[levels_len+1] = 'Other'
y = table(x)/length(x)
y1 = as.vector(y)
y2 = names(y)
y2_len = length(y2)

for (i in 1:y2_len) {
    if (y1[i]<=p){
          x[x==y2[i]] = 'Other'
        }
     }
x <- droplevels(x)
x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the package dplyr, and assuming your data frame (let's call it State) has one field called ID for each State name...

```
filtered_data <-  State %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n = n(), 
                                                       freq = n/nrow(State),  
                                                       above_thresh = freq > 0.2) 

filtered_data$State[filtered_data$above_thres == TRUE] <- "above_0.2"
```

effectively what this does is gives the state name of anything with a frequency of 0.2, the label "above_0.2".

Answer (score 0):

I'm including an option that uses makes the change to the factor levels attribute as an alternative to Ananda Mahto's answer.  The efficiency (based on a factor of 10,000 observations with 10 factors) isn't much different (about 150 microseconds), so your choice of option would likely depend on if you want to work with factors or with strings.  Personally, I'd choose to work with strings and would use Ananda's approach.

```
#* Using a list assignment to levels
combineByThreshold <- function(x, threshold = .02, label = "Other")
{
  prop <- prop.table(table(x))
  combine <- which(prop < threshold)

  levels(x) <- c(mapply(identity, levels(x)[-combine], SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES=TRUE),
                 setNames(list(levels(x)[combine]),
                     "Other"))
  x
}

#* Ananda Mahto
condenseMe <- function(vector, threshold = 0.02, newName = "Other") {
  toCondense <- names(which(prop.table(table(vector)) < 0.02))
  vector[vector %in% toCondense] <- newName
  vector
}

#* F.R.
collapsecategory <- function(x, p) {
levels_len = length(levels(x))
levels(x)[levels_len+1] = 'Other'
y = table(x)/length(x)
y1 = as.vector(y)
y2 = names(y)
y2_len = length(y2)

for (i in 1:y2_len) {
    if (y1[i]<=p){
          x[x==y2[i]] = 'Other'
        }
     }
x <- droplevels(x)
x
}

#* Steven Le

filtered_data <-  State %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n = n(), 
                                                       freq = n/nrow(State),  
                                                       above_thresh = freq > 0.2) 

filtered_data$State[filtered_data$above_thres == TRUE] <- "above_0.2"


#**************************
#* Comparison of methods
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)

x <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10000, 
            prob = rep(c(1, 20), c(4, 6)),
            replace = TRUE)

x <- as.factor(x)

DF <- data.frame(x = x) %>%
  mutate(x = as.character(x),
         orig = x)

microbenchmark(
  combineByThreshold = combineByThreshold(x),
  condenseMe = condenseMe(as.character(x)),
  collapsecategory = collapsecategory(x, .02),
  dplyr = {Ref <- DF %>%
             group_by(orig, x) %>%
             summarise(n = n(), 
                       freq = n/nrow(DF),  
                       above_thresh = freq < 0.02)
           Ref$x[Ref$above_thres == TRUE] <- "Other"
           DF <- left_join(DF[, "orig", drop=FALSE], Ref[, c("orig", "x")],
                           by = c("orig" = "orig"))
  }
)
Unit: microseconds
               expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 combineByThreshold  694.108  715.0740  872.8452  735.4550  771.5235 3403.971   100
         condenseMe  756.275  771.9635  893.2784  789.5585  827.9730 3753.223   100
   collapsecategory 3679.032 3713.1955 4156.7700 3772.1375 3949.4030 6852.219   100
              dplyr 4101.596 4229.0105 4515.9785 4408.6220 4602.4560 7772.711   100
```

Brief disclaimer: I may not have represented Steven Le's answer fairly here.  I interpreted his answer as generating a reference table of the new factor levels that could be merged back into the original data.  Someone please correct me if I've misinterpreted.