# Better way to write this R data-cleaning function?

Tags: r

I am writing a R function that takes a dataframe column (probably preferably of type factor) and clumps together all the entries below a user-defined frequency as "other." This is done for data cleaning.

Here is what I have written:

```
zcut <- function(column, threshold){
  dft <- data.frame(table(column))
  dft_ind <- sapply(dft$Freq, function(x) x < threshold)
  dft_list <- dft[[1]][dft_ind]
  levels(column)[levels(column) %in% dft_list] <- "Other"
  return(column)
}
```

I think this is pretty straightforward, but are there ways to make my code more concise or exact?

I would have asked this on the Code Review stack exchange, although it's not clear to me many R experts lurk there.

Comment: Here are a variety of ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34385340/

Comment: Having a "factor", `table` respects its `levels`, so you could just replace the low frequency "levels" with `levels(column)[table(column) < threshold] = "Other"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sapply` here. Try:

```
dft_ind <- dft$Freq < threshold
```

This should speed up the function in the case of large data.frames.