# Python: Combining Low Frequency Factors/Category Counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, categorical-data

There is a great [solution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385340/combining-low-frequency-counts-in-r).

My `df.column` looks like:

```
Windows
Windows
Mac
Mac
Mac
Linux
Windows
...
```

I want to replace low frequency categories with 'Other' in this `df.column` vector. For example, I need my `df.column` to look like

```
Windows
Windows
Mac
Mac
Mac
Linux -> Other
Windows
...
```

I would like to rename these rare categories, to reduce the number of factors in my regression. This is why I need the original vector. In python, after running the command to get the frequency table I get:

```
pd.value_counts(df.column)


Windows          26083
iOS              19711
Android          13077
Macintosh         5799
Chrome OS          347
Linux              285
Windows Phone      167
(not set)           22
BlackBerry          11
```

I wonder if there is a method to rename 'Chrome OS', 'Linux' (low frequency data) into another category (for example category 'Other', and do so in an efficient way.

Comment: How to define term low frequency data here. You mean less than 400?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where do you get the factors / frequencies from?

Comment: Anything from threshold of total sum to any given value. Value in % would be more robust

Comment: @mrCarnivore I'm trying to combine all categories under Macintosh into one that's called 'Other'

Comment: Please tell us your threshold then. It is an integral part of the question.

Comment: I'm assuming the threshold can be adjusted, since it's a constant, but 400/65k is bit less than 1%

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mask by finding percentage of occupency i.e :

```
series = pd.value_counts(df.column)
mask = (series/series.sum() * 100).lt(1)
# To replace df['column'] use np.where I.e 
df['column'] = np.where(df['column'].isin(series[mask].index),'Other',df['column'])
```

To change the index with sum :

```
new = series[~mask]
new['Other'] = series[mask].sum()

Windows      26083
iOS          19711
Android      13077
Macintosh     5799
Other          832
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

If you want to replace the index then :

```
series.index = np.where(series.index.isin(series[mask].index),'Other',series.index)

Windows      26083
iOS          19711
Android      13077
Macintosh     5799
Other          347
Other          285
Other          167
Other           22
Other           11
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**

```
(series/series.sum() * 100) # This will give you the percentage i.e 

Windows          39.820158
iOS              30.092211
Android          19.964276
Macintosh         8.853165
Chrome OS         0.529755
Linux             0.435101
Windows Phone     0.254954
(not set)         0.033587
BlackBerry        0.016793
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

`.lt(1)` is equivalent to  lesser than 1. That gives you a  boolean mask, based on that mask index and assign the data

Comment: Thanks, but this would change the output for the table only, not change the column itself. I'd like to go through every value in the df.column, and reassign the low frequency categories with other

Comment: create a dict and replace it back

Comment: @Bharath Thank you, but I'd like to replace them in the original vector, not the frequency table. Frequency table is taken from the vector data. (I showed what the vector looks like in the question)

Comment: That was a lot of answer in one question. Hope the edits answer your question. Do vote if the solution was helpful. Have a good day :)

Comment: @Bharath This still only changes the frequency table, I would like to change the data frame column instead. Please see my edit, I illustrated it in more detail

Comment: You havent read the answer from beginning after the update. I have posted the answer for that. The third line of the code is what you are after.

Comment: Yes of course, my apologies. This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 7):

This is a (late) extension to your question; it applies the rationale of combining low-frequency categories (in proportion less than `min_freq`) to the columns of an entire dataframe. It is based on @Bharath's answer.

```
def condense_category(col, min_freq=0.01, new_name='other'):
    series = pd.value_counts(col)
    mask = (series/series.sum()).lt(min_freq)
    return pd.Series(np.where(col.isin(series[mask].index), new_name, col))
```

A simple example of application:

```
df_toy = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4] + [5]*100, 'y': [5, 6, 7, 8] + [0]*100})
df_toy = df_toy.apply(condense_category, axis=0)
print(df_toy)

#          x      y
# 0    other  other
# 1    other  other
# 2    other  other
# 3    other  other
# 4        5      0
# ..     ...    ...
# 99       5      0
# 100      5      0
# 101      5      0
# 102      5      0
# 103      5      0
# 
# [104 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I'm a newbie, I use your function like this,`df['server_type_'] = df['server_type'].apply(condense_category)`, but it reports an error:`'str' object has no attribute 'isin'`,Can you offer some advice?

Comment: My function uses the `.apply` method to a pandas DataFrame, instead you are using it on a pandas Series. I suggest you to have a look at the [answer above mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47418479/7465462), which does this process for a Series instead of a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you, it was my negligence, and thank you again for your answer.