# How can I convert the python code that combines low frequency categories/values to a function that can be applied to any pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

For this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418299/python-combining-low-frequency-factors-category-counts)
Is there an easy way to define this code within a function such that i can apply it to any dataframe column.

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: links to another question aren't enough, your own question should be independently complete. Also, If you are familiar with how to access a specific column in pandas, converting already existing code into a function shouldn't be difficult at all. Make a variable name for your parameter, substitute all hardcoded values for your parameter, and you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution should be simplify with `normalize=True` in [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
def replace_thresh(df, col, thresh, new_val):
    s = df[col].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
    df[col] = np.where(df[col].isin(s.index[s < thresh]), new_val, df[col])
    return df

df = replace_thresh(df, 'col', 1, 'Other')
```