# Combining levels with low frequency in categorical features

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine levels in categorical feature that has 315 levels. 
My code to find the frequency of each level is :

```
for feature in categorical:
   percentage = df[feature].value_counts()/len(df)*100
   print("Feature {}: \n{}".format(feature,percentage))
```

When "categorical" it's a list with all categorical features in the data set. 
I can see the 'Feature_13' includes 315 levels, most of them with frequency lower than 0.01.

How can I efficiently combine the levels with low frequency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Combining Low Frequency Factors/Category Counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418299/python-combining-low-frequency-factors-category-counts)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to remove those with frequency (not actual value) less than 0.01.

```
for feature in categorical:
  df[feature] = df[feature].mask(df[feature].map(df[feature].value_counts(normalize=True)) < 0.01, 'Other')
```

As you know, `df[feature].value_counts(normalize=True)` returns a Series. Then, method `map` uses this series as a dictionary to map cell values into corresponding frequency. With the condition `< 0.01`, we can screen out those with frequency less than 0.01. In the end, function `mask` helps convert values of those valid cells into 'Other.'

If you like to know how much the threshold value should be for grouping rare categorical values into a single collection, here is the example. Suppose we want to group rare categorical values that consists of the lower 10% of the distribution of frequency.

```
frequencies = df[feature].value_counts(normalize=True, ascending=True)
threshold = frequencies[(frequencies.cumsum() > 0.1).idxmax()]
```